Get object from s3 in Express JS server and send it as response
Upon authorized request of a client, I want to send back all file back a file a response. Here, I'm getting the file from S3 bucket. What is the approach to send back the file back from S3 and sending it to a client?
const s3 = new S3Client({...})

router.get('/getfile', (req, res) => {
  const data = await s3.send(
    new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: 'bucket',
      Key: 'path',
    })
  )

  // an efficient way to send back the file
  // res.send(fileStream)
})


How can I send back the data?

Use pipe() to push the stream to the response.
const { Body, ContentType, ContentDisposition } = await s3.send(command);

res.setHeader('Content-Type', ContentType);
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', ContentDisposition || `attachment; filename="untitled"`);

Body.pipe(res);


I have following version "@aws-sdk/client-s3@^3.0.0" and it does not show a pipe function on Body which is of type StreamingBlobPayloadOutputTypes

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-smithy-types/TypeAlias/StreamingBlobPayloadOutputTypes/

I just tried it and confirmed there is pipe. Remember this is on the Body property of the s3 response
